# How do I pull text from a cell in a different sheet if the cell two columns away contains specific text?

Tags: excel

So essentially what I am trying to do is make name-tags in a spreadsheet for an attendance list I have created in a separate spreadsheet.
I have their full names in one column, and two columns over I have what colour they have been assigned to. 
I have separate spreadsheets for each colour for the name-tags.

I want the formula to be written in a separate spreadsheet, let's call it "Green 20". So Green 20 would have multiple cells containing the formula that does the following:

1. Check to see if the word "Pink" is in a cell between `D6:D100` in Spreadsheet
2. If "Pink" is in the cell, I want the formula to look at the row "Pink" is in and print out cell B? (? meaning whatever row it is) that contains the attendee's name.

So essentially the formula has to get data from a separate spreadsheet, check column D for specific text containing a colour, if the text is in one of the cells in the column then it needs to check the row the text is in and print out the text (First name and last name) in column B corresponding to the row that colour was in.

Comment: look into INDEX with MATCH to find the row.

Comment: Hello Daiana, and welcome to the site.  We like to keep things down to the nuts-and-bolts in questions and answers, so I went ahead and trimmed your question down.  Feel free to edit it again.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually went ahead and wrote a macro with one of my co-workers and this is what it ended up looking like:

Public Sub NameTags()

' NameTags Macro
' March 20

Dim Rng As Range
   Set Rng = Range("$B$5:$E$100")

Dim rowcount, colselect As Integer
   rowcount = 1
   colselect = 2

```
Sheets("March 20, 2017").Range("$B$4:$E$100").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Green"


For Each Row In Rng.Rows
    'MsgBox Row.Row
    If Cells(Row.Row, 2).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

        If Cells(Row.Row, 2).Value <> "" Then
            copystring = Cells(Row.Row, 2).Value & " " & Cells(Row.Row, 3).Value
            Sheets("Green 20").Cells(rowcount, colselect) = copystring

            Sheets("Green 20").Activate
            Cells(rowcount, colselect).Select
            Set mergecellrng = Cells(rowcount, colselect)
            Set mergecellrng2 = mergecellrng.Offset(0, 3)
            Range(mergecellrng, mergecellrng2).Merge
            mergecellrng.Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
            mergecellrng.Font.Size = 22
            mergecellrng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            mergecellrng.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

            If colselect = 8 Then
                rowcount = rowcount + 7
            End If
            Select Case colselect
                Case 2
                    colselect = 8
                Case 8
                    colselect = 2
            End Select
        End If
    End If
    Sheets("March 20, 2017").Activate
Next
```

An it repeats for each colour